# How to analyze webservice delay

Tags: c#, .net, performance, web-services, wcf

I need help to find a strategy to analyze a problem.
Suddenly, my application starts to behave strange.

**Summarizing, my application**

```
1. (.net 4.0) uses a webservice 
2. (svc, .net 3.5) that executes some procedures. I measured the time of procedures and total time is under the one second (call this time).
```

Most of the time the wait is few milliseconds: fair enough.

Sometimes though (and unfortunately seems to be random), wait can go up to a couple of minutes and then goes to timeout (correctly); if I check for time, it is still under one second.

Where am I losing this time?

How can I figure out what is happening?

**Do you have any tools, hints or whatever to suggest me to understand what is going on?**

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In a similar situation, I would start with the following:

- Configure WCF Tracing on both the client and service
  ... (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025(v=vs.110).aspx)
- Configure Fiddler to view the web service communications.
  ... The [Fiddler and Monitoring Web Service Traffic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16223324/fiddler-and-monitoring-web-service-traffic) SO post provides good reference links.
- Configure performance monitor with WCF counters
  ... Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) includes a large set of performance counters, scoped to three different levels: Service, Endpoint and Operation, which will help monitor application performance.  The MSDN article provides a detailed explanation:
  ... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735098(v=vs.110).aspx
- Conduct a network trace to watch the actual network traffic

Note: The following article provides a really good overview of WCF performance optimization:
http://weblogs.asp.net/sweinstein/archive/2009/01/03/creating-high-performance-wcf-services.aspx

Good luck.

Comment: I saw that the situation is drammatically improved (the problem is happening much less often) using _using_ statement around the creation of the WCF client...how do you think the two things could be linked?

Comment: The following article may provide some insight:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2007/10/27/performance-improvement-of-wcf-client-proxy-creation-and-best-practices.aspx